Exporting feature to shapefile using ArcGIS Pro
According to a third-party YouTube video from 2021 named Exporting to Shapefile with ArcGIS Pro, to export a feature to a shapefile, using a version available at that time, you right click on the feature and then go to Data -> Export Features. In the video this is the resultant dialog that comes up:

On my ArcGIS Pro 3.3.2 install I'm seeing Input Features and Output Feature Class but not Output Location or Output Name:

How do I export a feature (a polygon, in this case) to a shapefile using ArcGIS Pro 3.3.2?

Click in output box and go to the left. You'll see path to default gdb/suggested name. Change it to folder, eg type c:/scratch/export.  No need to add .shp

Or click on the folder icon on the right, navigate to where you want to save it and input the name (if you navigate to a folder it will save as shapefile)

Another thing worth thinking about, is why export to shapefile? File geodatabases are a superior format to shapefile. So unless you are exporting for it to be used by some other application I would personally avoid exporting to shapefile.

Output Feature Class is a combination Output Location and Output Name. By default it only shows the output file name, but once you click into that field you can see the full path.
To export to shapefile edit the path to be a folder (not .gdb) and then end the file in .shp. You would go from something like "..\fullpath\mygdb.gdb\vector" to "..\fullpath\vector.shp"
